# How to Validate a readonly="readonly" situation

Tags: javascript

In javascript, how can I check to see if an item, say "emailAddrs" that is set as readonly="readonly" has a value as I need to perform validation for situations like this before the form is submitted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<input>').val('lol').attr('readonly','readonly').appendTo('body').val()
```

Querying a readonly should work as normal. If not, can you provide a testcase?